# I heard that Python has automated "garbage collection" , but C++ does not. What does that mean?

Tags: c++, python, garbage-collection

I heard that Python has automated "garbage collection" , but C++ does not. What does that mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That means that python user doesn't need to clean his dynamic created objects, like you're obligated to do it in C/C++.

Example in C++:

```
char *ch = new char[100];
ch[0]='a';
ch[1]='b';
//....
// somewhere else in your program you need to release the alocated memory.
delete [] ch; 
// use *delete ch;* if you've initialized *ch with new char;
```

in python:

```
def fun():
    a=[1, 2] #dynamic allocation
    a.append(3)
    return a[0]
```

python takes care about "a" object by itself.

Comment: Although, if you are using 'delete' (whatever the flavor) you are doing C, not C++...

Comment: Don't confuse people, You are totally wrong.
Memory release in C is done by:
"free(ch)"
...

Comment: @bua - this is C++, not C. You use malloc() and free() together, or new and delete together. In C++ prefer new and delete as they are overloadable per object.

Comment: @Tom Leys: I've written that "Example in C++" in my answer, tree comments above Mr. Matthieu M. wrote that 'delete' is C not C++.
2 comments above I've respond to MR. Matthieu, that C mem release would be "free(ch)", Now You send spam writing that this is C++, not C. Lord I've wrote example in C++, where did you find that I've wrote that this is C ??? Please learn reading with understanding again.

Comment: Sorry @bua, I was actually responding to @Matthieu, but was expanding on your comment. I got confused and posted the wrong name.

Answer (score 12):

Try [reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) up on it.

Answer (score 4):

From Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29:

...

*Garbage collection frees the programmer from manually dealing with memory allocation and deallocation. As a result, certain categories of bugs are eliminated or substantially reduced:*

- *Dangling pointer bugs, which occur
  when a piece of memory is freed while
  there are still pointers to it, and
  one of those pointers is used.*
- *Double free bugs, which occur when
  the program attempts to free a

  region of memory that is already

  free.*
- *Certain kinds of memory leaks, in
  which a program fails to free

  memory that is no longer referenced

  by any variable, leading, over time,*
  to memory exhaustion.

...

*The basic principles of garbage collection are:*

1. *Find data objects in a program that cannot be accessed in the future*
2. *Reclaim the resources used by those objects*

Answer (score 3):

Others already answered the main question, but I'd like to add that garbage collection is possible in C++. It's not that automatic like Python's, but it's doable.

Smart pointers are probably the simplest form of C++ garbage collecting - [`std::auto_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/), [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm), [`boost::scoped_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) that release memory after being destroyed. There's an example in one of the earlier answers, that could be rewritten as:

```
boost::scoped_array<char> ch(new char[100]);
ch[0] = 'a';
ch[1] = 'b';
// ...
// boost::scoped_array will be destroyed when out of scope, or during unwind
// (i.e. when exception is thrown), releasing the array's memory
```

There are also [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), [`boost::shared_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) that implement reference counting (like Python). And there are full-blown garbage collectors that are meant to replace standard memory allocators, e.g. [Boehm gc](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).

Answer (score 2):

It basically means the way they handle memory resources. When you need memory you usually ask for it to the OS and then return it back.

With python you don't need to worry about returning it, with C++ you need to track what you asked and return it back, one is easier, the other performant, you choose your tool.

Answer (score 0):

As you have got your answer, now it's better to know the cons of automated garbage collection:
it requires large amounts of extra memory and not suitable for hard real-time deadline applications.

Comment: Python is known for its backend processing though...?